# Javadrone - How to get the drone info after connected into drone? E.G. Battery level, Altitude etc?

Tags: java, ar.drone

I am working on an application to control Parrot Ar.Drone using Javadrone API & its libraries. I am able to connect into drone & make it take off/land successfully.

Javadrone API can be download here : https://code.google.com/p/javadrone/downloads/list

However, I have no idea how to extract out drone's info that I wanted. I was trying to call the appropriate function. But it can't works.

**My code:**

```
import com.codeminders.ardrone.NavData;

In my class : -
    //declare a jlabel for battery level 
    public NavData data;
    public int value = data.getBattery();
    JLabel batteryStatus = new JLabel(); 

    batteryStatus.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);    
    batteryStatus.setText(data.getBattery()+ " %");

    if (value < 15) {
            batteryStatus.setForeground(Color.RED);
    } else if (value < 50) {
            batteryStatus.setForeground(Color.ORANGE);
    } else {
            batteryStatus.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    }
```

Any idea how to make it works ? If I run this snippet of code, it won't run since it will compilation stucks at getBattery() method. I wanted to implement this calling function in project so that relevant flight info. such as altitude can be shown on my apps. Thanks.

**The output of code compilation:**

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ardrone.arDroneFrame.jButtonConnectActionPerformed(arDroneFrame.java:462)
LINE 462 : batteryStatus.setText(data.getBattery()+ " %");
```

Comment: I am not sure if it is just the snippet you posted, but `data` is never initialized in the code you posted. So `data.getBattery()` causes your NullPointer.

Comment: Hi Jacob, thanks for pointing out. But the variable "data" is an object that I used to call "NavData" class method - getBattery() method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `com.codeminders.ardrone.NavDataListener` interface.

1. Implement the [`NavDataListener` interface, and the
   `navDataReceived` method](https://github.com/vzaliva/javadrone/blob/439d23e9fb9a7e2d3a0b59a7ab7257309bf0fbef/javadrone-api/src/main/java/com/codeminders/ardrone/NavDataListener.java).
2. Add your listener using the [`ARDrone`
   method `addNavDataListener`](https://github.com/vzaliva/javadrone/blob/439d23e9fb9a7e2d3a0b59a7ab7257309bf0fbef/javadrone-api/src/main/java/com/codeminders/ardrone/ARDrone.java#L231).
3. In your `navDataRecieved` method
   you will receive a NavData object with valid telemetry data.

Comment: Thanks John for your advice. I have no idea that I might need the "com.codeminders.ardrone.NavDataListener" interface for this purpose. I will give it a try and hopefully it works. I will update you as soon as I implement all the necessary steps into my code.

Comment: Thanks John. Now I did managed to get the telemetry data from drone. You are right. In order to get all the correct Nav data, we must connect into drone and make it (at least) take off. Thank you again, John. :)